# Opera browser extension approval

Tags: browser, opera, opera-extension

I've uploaded new browser extension to Opera addons and I've sibmitted the version from 1 week, but till now there is no response, is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

Extensions submitted to [Opera Add-Ons](https://addons.opera.com) are manually reviewed, and this takes time.

If the extension is minified or obfuscated, the moderators will ask you to provide source code and the way to reproduce submitted files. Such extensions have lower priority in the review queue.

Adhering strictly to [the acceptance criteria](https://dev.opera.com/extensions/acceptance-criteria/) and some patience will make the trick.